# Python: when does a thread terminate? Oviously not (immediately) at return

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I am using a `threading.Thread()` that does its job and `return`s.
Its return is documented in a print statement, so I am sure that
this happens. However, relying on `threading.active_count()` and `threading.enumerate()` the thread remains active!

Besides from joining the thread from the `MainThread`, is there 
anything else that can be done from within the thread to 
safely terminate?

Comment: For how long does the thread remain alive after `run()` has returned? Are you starting your own thread, or using a thread pool?

Comment: There might be a programming or logic error in your measurements. Why don't you show us a [complete](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example?

Comment: The code would not contain the slightest strange thing--only basics. That is, a 'Thread(target=f)' object is created, the function 'f' returns and 'threading.active_count() > 1'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `threading` module maintains a list of threads that have been started but have not been joined. It calls it an "active" list but really its an "not yet joined" list. When the program terminates, the threading module will do a join on whatever is left in the list. This lets you do a lazy exit where the program will stay running until all of its worker threads complete.

You can skip the active list by making the thread a "daemon". In this case it won't appear in the active list or be in the active count.

```
thread = threading.thread(target=somefunction)
thread.daemon = True
thread.start()
```

You can manage the deamon flag if you create your own threading subclass. It can even start itself, to simplify what the caller does.

```
class MyWorker(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.daemon = True
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        print("do your stuff here")

# example
MyWorker()
```

Comment: I guess, I cannot make it a deamon from within the thread's context, can I?

Comment: Yes, kind of. `threading` checks the flag when the thread is started, so it needs to be set before `start` is called. You can write a child `threading.Thread` subclass that sets the flag in its `__init__` and as long as callers use that object, it will work. Generally though, its the thing that makes a thread that should decide how that thread's expiration is handled. But writing your own subclass will work.